# Angular .run() initialising controller values

Tags: angularjs

This is my first AngularJS build and I'm totally new to it (I'm primarily a back-end dev).

I need to store some global values, which will then be used by other controllers/directives on the page and will also be passed into API calls to the backend. I'm trying to avoid using the $rootScope and think I can manage this by creating a service to store global/session type values.

I want to be able to load these 'session' values before any other controllers are run.

Everything seems to be working ok - my backend api is being hit and returning a JSON object but I think the homeCtrl is firing too soon, as I am getting a 'Cannot read property of 'user' undefined'.  If I console.log(response.data) then I can see the JSON object so I know it's being returned but this occurs AFTER the user undefined error.

So I think have something wrong with regard to timings and promises.

How should I go about creating a service that I can populate properties on initialise and then share between controllers/directives?

Any pointers or help appreciated

My app JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
/* Set our routing and templates */
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    /*Enable HTML5 mode - removes # from URL*/
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'homeCtrl',
            template: '<h2 ng-controller="homeCtrl">We are home</h2><p>User type string: {{ userType }}</p>'
        })
        .when('/my-status', {
            template: '<h2>We are my profile</h2>'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}])

/* gather Global variables and store */
.run(['mySession',function(mySession){
    mySession.init();
}]);


app.controller('homeCtrl', ['mySession', function ($scope, mySession) {

$scope.userType = (mySession.employeeType == "1") ? "Admin" : "User";

}]);

app.factory('mySession',['$http','$q',function($http, $q){

    var user = {};
    var displayState = 0;


    return {
        init : function(){
           return $http.get('/api/users/1')
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                        this.user = response.data;
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }

                }, function(response) {
                    // something went wrong
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: you have no access to the `user` object itself ...add it to return object

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use : ngStorage that let you use Storage (persistant other multiple session) & Session ( one session only)

See official doc here : https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Then, to initialise them before anything, initiliase them into `app.run()`

To use it, inject ngStorage to each of the controllers/ services that needs those values